# Get Variable with Variable

Tags: php, variables, get

I have a very simple question and I don't know why I can't get it to work.  I have a variable that I want to retrieve a GET variable with like this:

```
$name = "Test";
echo $_GET[$name];
```

For some reason this is not echoing anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Clarification: It works when i manually type the variable like this:

```
echo $_GET['Test']
```

This works fine, its only when i try to pass the var into the get it doesn't work.

SOLUTION: Sorry to waste everyone's time. I found the problem. I needed to wrap my variable $test in trim function to remove extra white space as the var was coming from an explode function and adding a space.  Thanks.

Comment: $_GET suggests that you're getting user input from a web page. Can you show the HTML of that page? Otherwise just echo $name;

Comment: *"For some reason this is not echoing anything."* Which means `$_GET['Test']` doesn't exist. Solution: Use the correct array index or provide the `Test` parameter. Not much we can do here, since we don't know anything about the context.

Comment: It's not possible the second code piece works but the first doesn't. You not showing the code you actually execute.

Answer (score 1):

I bet that if you try an URL like this:

```
http://localhost/?test=123
```

but the array key is case sensitive.

```
$name = "test";
echo $_GET[$name];
```

If you submit the data through a formular or other POST method, use `$_POST[$name]` instead. If in doubt, use `$_REQUEST[$name]`.